# Facebook iOS SDK - share user photo

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-ios-sdk

I need to upload photo to user's album and let user share with some messages. I've uploaded photo to app album using `[FBRequestConnection startForUploadPhoto:photo completionHandler:handler]`, but is there any way to share the uploaded picture?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the startWithGraphPath method provide in the Facebook SDK:

```
+ (FBRequestConnection*)startWithGraphPath:(NSString*)graphPath
                            parameters:(NSDictionary*)parameters
                            HTTPMethod:(NSString*)HTTPMethod
                     completionHandler:(FBRequestHandler)handler;
```

Here my code I used to upload a photo with a message, so the photo appear on my timeline with the message:

```
- (void) requestPostPhoto:(UIImage *)photo withMessage:(NSString *)message
{
    if( [self isLocalUserConnected] )
    {
        NSMutableDictionary * params = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
        if( message != nil || ![message isEqualToString:@""] )
        {
            [params setObject:message forKey:@"message"];
        }

        [params setObject:UIImagePNGRepresentation(photo) forKey:@"picture"];        
        [FBRequestConnection startWithGraphPath:@"me/photos"
                                     parameters:params
                                     HTTPMethod:@"POST" completionHandler:^(FBRequestConnection * connection, id result, NSError * error)
         {
             //TODO: add some code here
         }];
    }
}
```

I think you can change in the startWithGraphPath: the @"me" by the facebook user ID.